Let $F$ be a field and $R=\operatorname{End}_{F}(F[x])$. Prove or disprove that $R^2\cong R$ as rings.

Let $F$ be a field and $R=\operatorname{End}_{F}(F[x])=\operatorname{Hom}_{F}(F[x],F[x])$. Prove or disprove that $R^2\cong R$ as rings.

This question is from my homework. The original question only asked me to prove it, but then my professor modified it by changing "as rings" to "as $R$-module", which made the problem much simpler. However, this made me curious whether the original statement was correct.
To find an $R$-module isomorphism, I construct $\Phi:R\to R^2$ by $\Phi(f)=(\pi_{1}\circ f,\pi_{2}\circ f)$, where $\pi_{k}\in \operatorname{End}_{F}(F[x]) $ by
$\pi_{1}(x^{2n})=x^n$, $\pi_{1}(x^{2n+1})=0$, and $\pi_{2}$ is defined in the similar way. But under this construction, $\Phi$ seems not to be a ring isomorphism.
Edit: My question is about proving the ring isomorphism, not the R-module isomorphism!

The OP is asking about an isomorphism of rings, and not modules...

Note that $R^2$ has central orthogonal idempotents $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$.
Thus, if $R \cong R^2$, then $R$ has central orthogonal idempotents $e_1, e_2 \in R$ such that $e_1 + e_2 = 1$.
In particular, $e_1, e_2 : F[x] \to F[x]$ would be central! However, the only central $F$-linear endomorphisms of $F[x]$ are "multiplication by $\lambda$" for some $\lambda \in F$.
Then $e_1, e_2$ being idempotents would imply that $e_1 = e_2 = 1$, but this contradicts orthogonality!
Thus, $R \ncong R^2$ as rings.

Oh lol, not my best moment. Thanks for the correction, fixed!

Using (central) idempotents is an excellent way to attack this question.  In this case, you can also avoid idempotents by noting that the center of $R$ is $F$, while the center of $R\times R$ is $F\times F$, which is not a field.

The thing about $F[x]$ here is that it's just a fancy way of writing a countable dimensional $F$ vector space $V$.  It's known that for any vector space $V_F$, $End(V_F)$ is a prime ring, which is to say two nonzero ideals cannot multiply to zero.
This is apparent from the fact that $V$ is a faithful $End(V_F)$ module, but you can also easy prove it from scratch that if $I$ is a nonzero ideal, then it necessarily contains all rank $1$ projections. These are idempotents, and it is easy to show you can't annihilate them all at once with something nonzero.
If $R\cong R\times R$ as rings, then the inverse images of $R\times\{0\}$ and $\{0\}\times R$ are two nonzero ideals that multiply to zero.
